# Anonymous types (classes features)

Tags: c#, .net, variables, var

I have one big difficulty. I got the question to answer: What features should MyClass have in order to be correct?

```
var myVariable = new MyClass { 25 };
```

I have tried to find the answer since friday but I have no results yet. Have you got any ideas about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things the class needs in order to be eligible for that syntax:

- It needs to implement `IEnumerable` (or some other interface that implies `IEnumerable` - it could also inherit from a base class that implements `IEnumerable`)
- It needs to implement an `Add(...)` method capable of receiving an `int` value

Any one of the following class declarations would do:

```
public class MyClass1 : IEnumerable
{
    public void Add(int i) { }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => null;
}

public class MyClass2 : IEnumerable
{
    public void Add(double i) { }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => null;
}

public class MyClass3 : IEnumerable
{
    public void Add(object i) { }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => null;
}
```

There are more types as well that the compiler can automatically cast the `int` value to, the above are just 3 different examples.

Answer (score 2):

It should have an `Add(int)` method. This is a collection initializer. `List` does it like this.

```
var myVariable = new List<int> { 25 };
```